Use filament 3 jetstream
How to use filament 3 jetstream with blade and livewire ?
I used below commands.
composer require laravel/jetstream

composer require filament/filament

php artisan jetstream:install livewire

npm install && npm run dev

But I am getting 404 page while I am trying to browse  http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/login.
How to debug the whole issue ?
I am learning filament 3, jetstream and livewire.

Have you run php artisan migrate?? Are you using laravel 11? If yes then also check version compatibility with the packages and Cross check your route defination.

Thanks @Subha. I am getting this output while I ran command php artisan route:list https://i.sstatic.net/ilIs8Ij8.png. Thanks.

Thanks @Subha. How can I check version compatibility with the packages and Cross check route definition ?

Yes, using npm run dev will fail when using Laravel Jetstream and Livewire.
It's watching the assets, but doesn't run the actual site to serve pages.
You're better off using php artisan serve instead. That will work.
I hope that this helps.
